# Hide empty fields in lightning:recordViewForm

Tags: lightning-aura-components

We're displaying a record using `lightning:recordViewForm`.

```
<lightning:recordViewForm recordId="{!v.recordId}" objectApiName="MyCustomObject__c">
    <lightning:outputField fieldName="Field1__c"/>
    <lightning:outputField fieldName="Field2__c"/>
    <lightning:outputField fieldName="Field3__c"/>
</lightning:recordViewForm>
```

Now, if `Field2__c` has no value, then we'll see the Label for `Field2__c` and a blank line.
Instead of the blank line we want to display a message, like `No value, please update this field` or something.

Is there any way for me to know whether the field has data or not and display the message accordingly? Something like

```
<aura:if isTrue="[test field has data]">
    <lightning:outputField fieldName="Field2__c"/>
    <aura:set attribute="else">
        <div>[field label]</div>
        <div>{!$Label.c.No_Field_Data}</div>
    </aura:set>
</aura:if>
```

I guess what I'm looking for is the output equivalent of `placeholder`.

Answer (score 1):

I found a hacky workaround: 
Add the filler text in CSS.

```
.THIS .slds-form-element__static:empty:after{ 
    /*Get empty field values, add text to its after pseudo-element*/
    content: 'No value, please update this field';
}
```

I know that this isn't a great solution. If the field has whitespace value `' '` then the CSS selector will skip it, but for now it will suffice.
Of course, I'm always open to a better solution that does **not** involve querying the database for the record in my controller and holding that in memory and comparing fields.